# nested cross validation vs. train-test split

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, machine-learning-model, cross-validation, performance

I am trying to understand the main benefits of conducting a nested cross-validation compared to a simpler train-test split. Let us say I would like to build a prediction model. I initially split my data so that 80% of it is used for training and the remaining 20% of it for testing. Then, I run CV on the 80% to tune the hyperparameters and finally run the model using the optimal hyperparameters on the test sample, in order to get an unbiased estimate of my model performance.

Now, my understanding is that nested-CV has two main benefits:

1. You get to use the entire data you have as part the training process (so the inner CV would essentially get to see all the data at some point).
2. The model performance estimate you get could be more stable (in the sense that it is not based on a single run using the test data, but on multiple runs.

Am I missing something? And from a practical standpoint, assuming a large-enough database, does one really gain much from adding the computational complexity of a nested-CV compared to a simpler train-test split?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. You get to use the entire data you have as part the training process (so the inner CV would essentially get to see all the data at some point).
> 2. The model performance estimate you get could be more stable (in the sense that it is not based on a single run using the test data, but on multiple runs.

You've covered the main benefits. However, it is important to point out that *more stable* specifically includes the benefit of not being dependent on *how* you split your data. With hold-out validation it may be that the distribution of your test set differs from your training set thereby violating *the* key assumption of having training and test data coming from the same distribution in order to obtain an unbiased estimate of the model's performance.

This is more likely to be a problem when the amount of data is limited. Therefore, when you have a very large dataset (and your model takes a long time to train) it is common to apply holdout validation (that is, k-fold CV for validation and holdout CV for testing). With models which are very costly to train (such as Neural Nets often are) it is common to apply holdout validation even to only medium-sized datasets (e.g. where medium-sized refers to not more than $200k$ datapoints as a ballpark figure).